# VBA User Form macro dependant combox boxes

Tags: excel, vba

I have been out of coding for a few years now, and not very familiar with Excel VBA so apologies if my question not clear enough.
I am creating User Forms in an Excel Accounting application for all my data entry etc.

I have already pre loaded combobox1 in my User Form with a list of names from a "Users" worksheet.
I now need to populate combobox2 with a list of stock located in Column 2 of an inventory worksheet.
However I am needing some help.
I am passing the selected value of Combobox1 as a parameter to a function as shown in a psuedo code below to intergate the inventory worksheet
How do I ensure the stock list returned = the users name in Column3 and also if column 4 meets a criteria

```
Sub Combobox1.Click()
Dim AName = Combobox1.selected value
Combobox2.list = getSpecificData(AName)
Combobox2.Listindex=0
end Sub

'I need help with this bit?
Function getSpecificData(AName as String)
 return stock in Column 1 from Inventory worksheet where column 3 = "AName" and Column 4 = "Avaialble"
Bind combobox2 with stock list
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You're likely better off with a `Combobox1_Change` event rather than the `Combobox1_Click` event:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim AName As String
    AName = ComboBox1.Value
    ComboBox2.List = getSpecificData(AName)
    ComboBox2.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

As for the `getSpecificData`, this works with arrays and feeds the array to the list of Combobox2 when ready, returns "No results" if none were found meeting the criteria:

```
Function getSpecificData(AName As String)
    Dim wsInv As Worksheet: Set wsInv = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory")
    With wsInv
        Dim i As Long, arr, rCount, arrInv, lRow As Long
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        arrInv = .Range("A2:D" & lRow)
        ReDim arr(1 To lRow - 1)
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrInv)
            If arrInv(i, 3) = AName And arrInv(i, 4) = "Available" Then
                rCount = rCount + 1
                arr(rCount) = arrInv(i, 1)
            End If
        Next i
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To IIf(rCount > 0, rCount, 1))
        If rCount = 0 Then arr(1) = "No results"
    End With
    getSpecificData = arr
End Function
```

You'll need to adjust where arrInv gets its values from depending on how your Inventory sheet looks like.